# asp net gridview to highcharts

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, highcharts

So I have a gridview in visual studio 2015 populated with data and with filter controls (via dropdown list).
I want to get a highcharts chart to display the gridview after it has been filtered to more easily trends in data.
I have dotnet.highcharts wrapper for asp.net and highcharts, but am unsure how gridview can be put into highchart chart. I am unsure how to implement this, the tutorials do not mention gridview.
I have exported gridview to csv file, and have seen that it is possible to use csv and push into highcharts, but this method is very slow.
My gridview updates every week with new data fed into it, so if there is a way to easily dynamically bind gridview to datatable/ allow it to be exported to highcharts, that would be useful.
 If any1 has a method of doing this, I would greatly appreciate a response (even if it is just to URL of existing tutorial for this).

Answer (score 0):

You can use it with [Javascript](http://www.aspdotnet-pools.com/2016/04/bind-gridview-to-datatable-and-convert.html) like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
    foo = {
        myAwesomeCallback: function (value) {
            return value + '$'
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('table#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').highchartTable();
    });

</script>
```